# Python, replacing the text to the specific format with regular expression

Tags: python, regex

So, I have been going through Regular Expression for a day and... I failed to achieve my expectation.....

There are two examples.

```
Before: This is a phrase from the book. (title_of_the_book 132:1~5)
 After: This is a phrase from the book. (title_of_the_book 132page 1row~5row)

Before: This is a phrase from the book. (title_of_the_book 133:1~134:3)
 After: This is a phrase from the book. (title_of_the_book 133page 1row~134page 3row)
```

I am willing to make a regular expression pattern that works for both cases.

It was still ugly, but was doable by myself when the phrase was within a single page like the first example. However, if the phrase is within multiple pages like the second example, it was out of my ability :/...

Could I please get a help?

Thank you!

God... when would I be able to master regular expression.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex to match your page/row numbers:

```
(\d+):(\d+)~(\d+)(?![:\d])|(\d+):(\d+)
```

It matches a pattern of page:row~row (as long as it is *not* followed by a `:`), or a pattern of page:row.

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ZCqdkn/3)

You can then use a lambda function to determine the appropriate replacement string based on which alternation was matched:

```
import re

lines = ['This is a phrase from the book. (title_of_the_book 132:1~5)',
         'This is a phrase from the book. (title_of_the_book 133:1~134:3)']

def repl(m):
    if m.group(1):
        return m.group(1) + 'page ' + m.group(2) + 'row~' + m.group(3) + 'row'
    return m.group(4) + 'page ' + m.group(5) + 'row'

for line in lines:
    out = re.sub(r'(\d+):(\d+)~(\d+)(?![:\d])|(\d+):(\d+)', lambda m: repl(m), line)
    print(out)
```

Output:

```
This is a phrase from the book. (title_of_the_book 132page 1row~5row)
This is a phrase from the book. (title_of_the_book 133page 1row~134page 3row)
```